# WP8.1 MapControl.TrySetViewBoundsAsync does nothing

Tags: c#, dictionary, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I just tried this and it does nothing. TrySetViewBoundsAsync returns false all the time except when MapAnimationKind.None is set, but still does nothing.

I have also tried TrySetViewAsync this does the same as above e.g. nothing

I'm trying to set the bounds of my map control to a route of points I just plotted

The route displays fine but I can't zoom the the extent of the route

I can set a manual zoom but that doesnt quite do what I want especially if the route is large or small

Any ideas ?

```
    private async void ShowMapRoute(List<BasicGeoposition> oMapRoute, bool ZoomToRoute = false)
    {
        if (oMapRoute.Count > 1)
        {
            MapPolyline oLine = new MapPolyline();
            oLine.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
            oLine.StrokeThickness = 5;
            oLine.Path = new Geopath(oMapRoute);
            myMap.MapElements.Add(oLine);

            if (ZoomToRoute)
            {
                GeoboundingBox oBoundingBox = GeoboundingBox.TryCompute(oMapRoute);

                myMap.Center = new Geopoint(oBoundingBox.Center);

                bool bSuccess = await myMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(oBoundingBox, null, MapAnimationKind.Default);

                if (!bSuccess) myMap.ZoomLevel = 9;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have manually checked the coordinates of my bounding box on a google map and they are correct.

Comment: Had the same problem just now, with me it was because the Map control wasn't loaded fully. So adding a Loaded event handler and only doing the TrySetViewBoundsAsync there did the trick

Comment: Event handler on loaded worked for me as well @Depechie .. I think that's the best answer to doing this cleanly

Answer (score 1):

Bit hard to see what you actually tried without any code examples... but I always use the following snippet to set the map correclty zoomed when a route is drawn.

So the list of basic geopositions is the actual route to be drawn on the map and after that I use the `TrySetViewBoundsAsync`method with a computed bounding box to zoom the map.

```
public async void SetMapPolyline(List<BasicGeoposition> geoPositions)
{
    var polyLine = new MapPolyline { Path = new Geopath(geoPositions), StrokeThickness = 4, StrokeColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["StravaRedColor"] };
    BingMapControl.MapElements.Add(polyLine);

    await BingMapControl.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(GeoboundingBox.TryCompute(geoPositions), null, MapAnimationKind.None);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my post with my code.  I tried reformatting to your example still no joy. `MapAnimationKind.Default` returns true but does nothing. All other `MapAnimationKind` return false and do nothing

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
bool bSuccess = false;

while (!bSuccess)
   bSuccess = await myMap.TrySetViewBoundsAsync(oBoundingBox, null, MapAnimationKind.Default);
```

Seems to do the trick